How can I properly use PWM to observe hopefully >= 2x normal efficacy, seeing the theoretical max of 1700 lm/W scotopic efficacy?
In a Wikipedia article on "Scotopic Vision", there is a section that states:

The maximum scotopic efficacy is 1700 lm/W at 507 nm (compared with 683 lm/W at 555 nm for maximum photopic efficacy).[11] While the ratio between scotopic and photopic efficacies is only around 2.5 counted at peak sensitivity the ratio increases strongly below 500 nm.

I want to build a device that achieves this astounding 1,700 lumen per watt efficacy.
PWM keeps the luminance above a certain level when it's on, using persistence of vision to cause the appearance of dimness, but I'm not sure that with the scotopic vision, which uses the rods instead of the cones of our sight, that PWM will not cause a problem, preventing attaining the 1,700 figure in practice.

EDIT 1:  (Feedback from a comment)
The wavelength of 507 nm is in, or very close to, the cyan color, so green light will probably not be very useful in this discussion.  (Yes, the other wavelength quoted, 555 nm, is a green, but that was for maximum photopic efficacy, not scotopic efficacy -- we are trying to achieve maximum scotopic efficacy in this question).

EDIT 2:  (Feedback from an answer)
I may use a small solar cell and a supercapacitor, if the energy is small enough, so the amount of energy really does matter.
Keep in mind that it's also about being undetected, both for spouses, and other needs for being undetected, TBD.

EDIT 3:  (Answered my own question)
Please see my answer.
I will consider other answers that are better.

I have decided that this question is hard to answer because I don't have measurements, and won't, until I order some green and cyan LED's, at which point I'll probably open up a new question anyway.
So, I will implement a flashlight, where I can both dim by changing the PWM duty cycle, and also dim by changing the amplitude (magnitude?) of the PWM peaks. I will then judge that I have achieved success if I can read using cyan 507nm, at half the power of reading using green 555nm, adjusted for the lm/w figures of the individual LED's actually used.  I'll update when I find out.
By the way, the white LED's may win in the end simply because they start out with such great lm/W figures.
Thanks all. (Especially Tim.)

Question clarification from comments:

I do not want to use a laser, although I heartily thank you because I now understand why a laser would come closer to the 1700 theoretical. (Does an inexpensive semiconductor laser at 507 nm exist?)  Here's what I want to do:


Using a Cyan LED light source, having a center wavelength reasonably close to the optimal 507nm, I only want to be able to read using hopefully less than half the power (half the lumens, which should appear brighter.) So this is reflected hopefully in the new title for the question.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It is not possible to actually build a 1700 lm/watt device in practice since power supplies, LEDs and even wires are not 100% efficient. A more reasonable figure given available LED technology would be 500-1000 lm/watt.
However, from your comments I think even aiming for this efficiency is pointless. At the low current you are considering, even a small battery will last for hundreds or thousands of hours, probably far longer than required. Trying to extend battery life from ten times longer than makes sense to 50 times longer than makes sense is unlikely to be worthwhile, especially when it will make your design needlessly complicated and expensive. An inexpensive 100 or 150 lm/watt white LED is likely fine for your application and will be much more pleasant to read with.

When a person in the third world has no electricity, and must work all month for a set of batteries, a device working on these principles would allow study at night to lift ones-self out of poverty. The ultra low current is a feature, not a bug. Perhaps you are not qualified to judge as you have. Remember, you're fortunate to be among the wealthy few in the world, and you have a responsibility to help others. (because you can).

@MicroservicesOnDDD If one is in poverty than it is doubly important to be cost effective, which is why using an inexpensive standard LED source would be a better choice.  Likewise, a feature of the very low current is that the efficiency is much less important, hence my point that making the device expensive in order to save a very small amount of power is a poor design choice.
